# Parse Login self.logInViewController ambiguous reference to member ' logInViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiviewcontroller

I am using parse's provided login code for their latest ParseUI. I am confused why I am getting this error every single time I use `self.logInViewController` and `self.signUpViewController`, the error being:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'logInViewController' and 'signUpViewController'

Here is my code:

```
import Parse
import ParseUI
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate  {

    @IBAction func simpleAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.presentViewController(self.logInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func customAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("custom", sender: self)

    }

    @IBAction func logoutAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        PFUser.logOut()

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {

            self.logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFields.LogInButton | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten | PFLogInFields.DismissButton

            var logInLogoTitle = UILabel()
            logInLogoTitle.text = "Parse"

            self.logInViewController.logInView.logo = logInLogoTitle

            self.logInViewController.delegate = self

            var SignUpLogoTitle = UILabel()
            SignUpLogoTitle.text = "Parse"

            self.signUpViewController.signUpView.logo = SignUpLogoTitle

            self.signUpViewController.delegate = self

            self.logInViewController.signUpController = self.signUpViewController

        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername username: String!, password: String!) -> Bool {


        if (!username.isEmpty || !password.isEmpty) {
            return true
        }else {
            return false
        }

    }

    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, didLogInUser user: PFUser!) {

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }

    func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, didFailToLogInWithError error: NSError!) {
        print("Failed to login...")
    }

    func logInViewControllerDidCancelLogIn(logInController: PFLogInViewController!) {

    }

    func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController!, didSignUpUser user: PFUser!) {

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
    func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController!, didFailToSignUpWithError error: NSError!) {

        print("FAiled to sign up...")

    }



    func signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController!) {

        print("User dismissed sign up.")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logInViewController` and `signUpViewController` are both undefined.

You need to define them with:

```
let logInViewController = PFLogInViewController()
let signUpViewController = PFSignUpViewController()
```